# polymorphic association without nested routes event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, polymorphism

I have 2 models article and forums which have polymorphic association with comments model.

I am using simple routes as follows.

**routes.rb** :

```
resources :articles 
resources :comments
resources :forums
```

following is my **models code for article and forum** :

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable,:dependent => :destroy
```

in **comments model** :

```
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

now when i enter `http://localhost:3000/articles/10`

it shows article content and below that previous comments on this article and a textarea to give new comments but when i click on create comments it goes to this url `http://localhost:3000/comments` and i get following error

```
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

following is my **comments controller code** :

```
def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])

  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved comment."
    redirect_to(articles_url, :notice => 'Articlecmnt was successfully created.')
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

def new
  @comment = Comment.new 
end

def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

following is my **index.html.erb** file code which i am rendering in articles and forums `show.html.haml` using  `= render :template=>"comments/index"`

```
<% form_for [@commentable, Comment.new] do |form| %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= form.text_area :commentcontent, :rows => 5 %></td>
      <td><%= form.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><%= submit_tag "Add comment" %></td></tr>
  </table>

<% end %>

<ul id="comments">
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <li>
    <p>
      <b>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</b>
    </p> 
    <%= comment.commentcontent %><b> by <%= @current_user.email %></b>
  </li>

  <% end %>
</ul>
```

how to solve this error? I think its not getting correct `article_id`. how can I strore correct `commentable_id` and `commentable_type`(article or forum) when creating new comments? Is there any other way than this `find_commentable`?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please indent your code in your answer and don't wait someone do it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You `find_commentable` method return the first params suffix by `_id` . It's seems doesn't works in your case. Why don't do a simple `User.find(params[:user_id])` ? It's more simple and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think that the error is because you are doing      @commentable.comments.new when should be @commentable.comments.build
 or in this case @commentable.comments.create